# Cant connect to OpenVPN

Tags: ssl, openvpn, centos

I have configured OpenVPN server (v2.4.9) on Centos 8, and want to connect from Yealink phones. One of the Yealink boxes (W60B) is unable to connect due to the following error:

```
TLS error: Unsupported protocol. This typically indicates that client and server have no common TLS version enabled. This can be caused by mismatched tls-version-min and tls-version-max options on client and server. If your OpenVPN client is between v2.3.6 and v2.3.2 try adding tls-version-min 1.0 to the client configuration to use TLS 1.0+ instead of TLS 1.0 only
 OpenSSL: error:14209102:SSL routines:tls_early_post_process_client_hello:unsupported protocol
```

I saw that Yealink box uses OpenVPN v2.1, which can connect only by TLS v1.0. My question is what can I do to establish this connection,  downgrade OpenVPN? or there is some way to force OpenVPN server use tls 1.0?

Comment: This doesn't look like a security question but a Yealink support question...

Comment: Yes, I opened a ticket with them about this, but here I want to know is there any way to use TLS 1.0 on server side, or I dont know exactly maybe my question doesn't make sense, please adivse.

Comment: Sounds like your Yealink boxes are severely out of date. You should update them as far as possible, or replace them.